# loadItem(); with localStorage (broken)

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, string, parsing

I have two function to saveItem() and other to loadItem(); but I need see my items "when I Refresh the Page", I am using localStorage to save data doing of this a JSON.

```
var input = document.getElementById('input');

function newItem(list, itemText){
    var item = document.createElement('li');
    item.className = 'item';
    item.innerText = itemText;
    list.appendChild(item);
    saveItem();
}

input.onkeyup = function(evt){
var key = evt.keyCode || evt.whitch;
    if(key == 13){
        itemText = input.value;
        console.log('createITem');
            if(!itemText || itemText == '' || itemText == ' '){
                return false;
            }
                newItem(document.getElementById('ul'), itemText);
     }
}

function saveItem(){
    var items = document.querySelector('li.item');
    var data  = Array.prototype.map.call(items, function(item){
        return [item.innerHTML];
    });
    localStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify(data));
}

function loadItem(){
    var items = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('data'));
    if(!items){
        return;
    }
    Array.prototype.map.call(items, function(item){
        return newItem(document.getElementById('content-memo'), item[0]);
    });
}

loadItem();
```

Comment: What is the problem you have?

Comment: @ianaya89 I need see my new Items created when "Browser Upload".

Comment: Sorry, but I don't get you. What do you mean with "Browser Upload"? Is an event? I think you are confused with "on load" event.

Comment: @ianaya89 When you update the website. :)

Comment: I think you mean "Refresh" the web page ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure `saveItem` is working? Your code shows you calling `loadItem`, but it doesn't show you calling `saveItem`. In any case, that's where your problem is.

If you open your Dev Tools pane and inspect localStorage (or from the console, see if `localStorage.data` is defined), you should see if it's working properly. If not, then of course `loadItem` won't work as expected.

In order to `map` all `li.item`s, you have to change the line from:

```
var items = document.querySelector('li.item');
```

To this:

```
var items = document.querySelectorAll('li.item');
```

`querySelector` will only return the first result as a DOM object, and you can't call `Array.prototype.map` on it. You need an array-like object. `queryItemSelectorAll` gives you that.

As it stands, the `Array.prototype.map` call in `saveItem` returns an empty array. So that's what gets set in `localStorage.data` - and thus what gets returned to the `map` function in `loadItem`.

Aside from that, are you having other troubles?

Comment: Yes, I do list.appendChild(item); and after saveItem();

Comment: Have you tried changing `querySelector` to `querySelectorAll` inside the `saveItem` function? Does it fix your problem?

Comment: You must change the code from `querySelector` to `querySelectorAll` as I suggest. Otherwise, it won't work. Make that change. Then explain what happens.

Comment: Is ok, a change and test now.